# how to send an uploaded file using ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, web-services, file-upload

I have a form as below...

```
<form  id="form2" name="form2" action="" method="post"  onsubmit="" enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="uploadForm" >
<div>
<span>File : </span>
</div>
<div>
<input type="file" id="filebrowse">
</div>
</form>
```

When i submit the form, i need to send the uploaded file to my REST webservices as param through ajax call.

I am totally confused as to how to do this.
Any pointers?

Comment: As far as i know, form with enctype multipart/form-data cant be sent via AJAX for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Googling first is always a good idea. tutsplus have kindly created [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/). There are also several Open Source AJAX file uploaders out there already, so you could consider either using one of those instead, or if creating your own is necessary perhaps take inspiration from those.